# Treating a crack in a concrete patio before resurfacing

Tags: concrete

I am resurfacing a covered outdoor concrete patio. The original slab has a crack in it due to some heave. I am not particularly worried about this crack, however. The soil below is hard clay, and the crack has not grown in many years.

However, I know that this crack will eventually make it through the resurfaced layer eventually. My question is what should I do to slow this process? The way I see it, I have a couple options:

- Fill the crack with some treatment material and resurface over;
- Install an expansion joint in the resurfaced layer that follows the crack as best as possible;
- Cut out around the crack, re-set concrete in that area with expansion joints on either side.

The final option is obviously the most work. But I'm not sure it's totally necessary. Are there good products available for crack treatment prior to resurfacing?

Comment: The correct answer will depend on how wide the crack is.

Comment: At its widest point, maybe 1/4".

Comment: For a small crack like this that isn't growing I believe you can just mix some of the resurfacing mix thicker to use for patching. The manufacturer of the mix should have instructions and likely tips on their website.